# Using borders on elements that have a linear gradient backgrounds causing solid colors on edges

Tags: html, css

When creating a span element that has a linear background, and no border, everything works fine.

[image: element without border]

But as soon as I add a border, the colors from the gradient become solid and just sit on the edges.

[image: element with border and color clipping]

Increasing the border size mitigates the issue, but I have found no way to completely remove the problem without increasing the border width or removing the border.

[image: element with much larger border]

CSS for the element:

```css
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0000ff, #ff0000);
color: white;
border: 3px solid black;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 3px;
font-size: 2vw;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black, -2px 2px 1px black;
```

Comment: Why would a solid border behave any differently? If you just want more spacing then use `padding` - or `border: 3px solid transparent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't simulate it, so, my suggestion is to change from border to box-shadow: check the snippet below:

```css
span{
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0000ff, #ff0000);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black, -2px 2px 1px black;
}

.border{
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.box-shadow{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<span class="border">My Contributions</span>
<br/> <br />
<span class="box-shadow">My Contributions</span>
```

Comment: What worked for me was just replacing the `border: 3px solid black;` line with `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;` and it looks great now! So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The starting and ending points of the gradient are at the edges of the padding-box and border. That's why as soon as you add a border, the colors from the gradient become solid and just sit on the edges.

Using box-shadow:inset will fix the issue. See the updated CSS below.

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0000ff, #ff0000);
color: white;
border: 3px solid black;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 3px;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px black;
font-size: 2vw;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black, -2px 2px 
1px black;
```